# How to open a new tab on onconfirm in facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

I want to open a new page with a specific link once a users click the ok button. I am using this code :

```
document.setLocation(link);
```

The problem is, with this code the new link opens in the same page. I want the new link to open in a new page.

Can anyone please help me ? Thanks.

-
ahsan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=216750#p216750

In short: it cant be done as of now.

Comment: I get the following error:     Error: a194182563946198_window is not defined

Comment: @Ahsan: Sorry, just noticed you were working with fbjs. Take a look at the link in the edited post above. :)